# Reordering of an overloaded Template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have a class `InsertStatement` that uses an external function `bind`:

```
namespace sqlite {

template <typename T>
inline void bind(SQLiteStatement &statement, size_t idx, const T &value) {
    statement.bind(idx, value);
}

template<typename ...FIELDS>
class InsertStatement {

   ...
   template <typename T>
   bool bindValue(int idx, const T& t) {
       sqlite::bind(*statement, idx+1, t);
       return true;
   }
   ...
};
```

The reason for using an external function is to be able to override it and support the use of other types in the `InsertStatement` class. For example, if I want to use it with `StrongType<T>`, I can do this:

```
template <typename T, typename TAG>
class StrongType {
private:
    T value;
public:
    StrongType (T&& v)
            : value(std::forward<T>(v)) {

    }

    T toValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }
};

namespace sqlite {

template <typename T, typename TAG>
inline void bind (SQLiteStatement &statement, size_t s, const StrongType<T,TAG> &strongType) {
    statement.bind(s, strongType.toValue());
}
}
```

The problem is that I need to include the `StrongType.h` *before* `InsertStatement.h`, otherwise the compiler is unable to resolve correctly the function call.

Though I can explain it intuitively, the question is, how can I avoid this problem? I don't want to `#include "StrongType.h"` from `InsertStatement.h` because `StrongType` is an external class not directly related to this library, and because this will indeed occurs with any new type, and I want to keep the class flexible enough.

I'm using different compilers (gcc, clang and MSVC), c++14 (c++17 or later is not an option for the moment).

1. How can I avoid this kind of "header ordering" problems?
2. What is the best approach to let a Templated class to be expanded with other types, whose details are unknown to the class?

Answer (score 1):

You might rely on [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) and have `bind` in same namespace than `StrongType`.
(you need to not use qualified call):

```
template <typename T>
bool bindValue(int idx, const T& t) {
    using sqlite::bind;
    bind(*statement, idx+1, t);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue. To compile I need to define `bind` with the `StrongType` argument before the generic `bind`, otherwise the compiler will try to instantiate something using the generic version. I think it is something related to the two-phase lookup, but I know pretty nothing about it and I can't understand if it is so or not. Thanks

Comment: No it should be visible each time you use `template<typename ...FIELDS>
InsertStatement::bindValue`.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. And I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'll try to provide a minimum compilable example, then.